# Group theory proof (with complex numbers)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

> Let $a$ be a subgroup of the [circle group $T$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group). Prove that $a^m=1$ and
>   $a^n=1$ if and only if $a^d=1$ for $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

Tried to prove in the forward direction by writing $a=e^{i\theta}$, $m=sd$, $n=td$.

Then,

$a^m= e^{isd\theta} = (e^{id\theta})^s = (a^d)^s = 1$

Similarly, $(a^d)^t = 1$.

So $a^d = 1$.

Feel like I'm doing something wrong here but can't really tell why. Would be great if someone could correct me here and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks it's fixed!

Comment: Did you read it before posting it?

Comment: MathJax tutorial? No sorry...It's kind of stupid but I didn't know it existed...

Comment: This is not entirely true. You've only used that $d$ is a _common divisor_ of $m$ and $n$, not that it is the _greatest_ common divisor. Thus you cannot conclude like you have.

Comment: d=gcd(m,n) would make s and t relatively prime? But how would that lead to the conclusion?

Comment: Converting $a$ to $e^{i\theta}$ is completely irrelevant the way you're reasoning. You could just as easily have reasoned $a^m=a^{sd}=(a^d)^s=1$

Comment: If m,n are non-zero integers then there exist integers c,d with mc+nd=gcd(m,n).

Comment: Yes I got it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Take a look at Bézout's identity to get the only if part.

Comment: Got it, thanks!